# The role of machine precision in the derivative approximation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

> You wish to compute of $f^{\prime}(x)$ using the approximation
> $$\widehat{f^{\prime}}(x)=\frac{f({x}+h)-{f}(x)}{h}$$ for some fixed $0<h<0.01$. Suppose that the computer already contains a built-in function for computing $f$, with relative errors less than machine precision, $t$, and you know the value of a constant $A$ satisfying $\left|f^{\prime \prime}(y)\right| \leq A$ for all $y$ with $|y-x|<0.01$. 
>  (a)  Estimate the total error incurred when computing $f^{\prime}(x)$. Give your answer in terms of $f(x), f^{\prime}(x)$, $h$ and $t$.

---

My attempt:

Taylors remainder theorem says $$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+(h^2/2!)f''(\zeta),~$$for some $\zeta \in (x,x+h)$. Now $$
\widehat{f^{\prime}}(x)=\frac{f({x}+h)-{f}(x)}{h}=f'(x)+(h/2)f''(\zeta),
$$
implies $$|\widehat{f^{\prime}}(x)-f'(x)| \leq (h/2)A,$$since $|\zeta-x|<0.01$.

Doubt:

What exactly is the role of $t$ here? How the relative error in computing $f$ using the  built in function comes into play?

Comment: Stepleman & Winarsky, "Adaptive Numerical Differentiation", Mathematics of Computation v. 33 n. 148 pp 1257-1264, October 1979.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not evaluate $f$, what you compute is $f(x)(1+\delta(x))$ with $|\delta(x)|< t$. Thus the evaluated difference quotient also gets an error term with upper bound $$\frac{2|f(x)|t}{h}.$$

If you want to go into weird details, note that the operation $x+h$ also has an error bounded by $|x|t$ (simplified, while $|h|\ll |x|$). This means that the evaluation of $f(x+h)$ has not only the error term bounded by $|f(x)|t$, but also an error term bounded  by about $$|f'(x)x|t.$$

---

**Example:** $f(x)=\sin x$ at $x=1$. The second error can be compensated by making the same error in the denominator, dividing by $((x+h)-x)$. The plot shows that this really makes a (small) difference

[image]

Comment: They said that the built-in $f$ has a given worst case relative error, so $|\delta(x)| \leq t |f(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: So the total error incurred can be bounded by $(2|f(x)|+|f'(x)x|)t/h+(h/2)A$, right?

Comment: Yes. And the optimal $h$ is around $\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Sir, How can we justify the machine epsilon error in calculating $f(x+h)$ includes a quantity bounded by $|f'(x)x|t$ ? This is the only point I missed here.

Comment: Decorate computer functions and operations with "FP". Then what you compute is \begin{align}f_{FP}(x+_{FP}h)&=f(x+_{FP}h)(1+δ_1)\\&\simeq f(x+h+(|x|+|h|)δ_2)+f(x)δ_1\\&\simeq f(x+h)+f'(x+h)|x|δ_2+f(x)δ_1\\&\simeq f(x+h)+f'(x)|x|δ_2+f(x)δ_1,\end{align} ignoring small quantities of second or higher order, that is, products and powers of small quantities.

Comment: It has been a long time since I worked on this, but back in 1979 it was shown that the best you can do for the derivative is 2/3 the bits of the function.  And to get that, start with a oversize h and decrease it until the change in difference quotient reverses.  The next to last step size is the optimum.  This was incorporated into the PPC rom for the HP 41c calculator.  Those machines are long obsoleted by the LISP machines, and more recently by the HP-Prime-- sadly, the last handheld computer HP shall produce.  For more, try hpmuseum.org or look into the last HHC conference rom.

Comment: @richard1941 : Yes, you get that for the central difference quotient where the best step size is $h\sim t^{1/3}$ and the resulting relative error $\sim t^{2/3}$.